# GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync custom expiry time

Tags: .net-core

I am using below code for 2FA but i wanted to increas time limit of 2 FA code.

Can anyone help me on this

var code = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);